# dismissViewControllerAnimated results in empty screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I present modal view which is a navigation controller:

```
 UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photoEditVC];
 [self  presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Once I'm done with the modal view, inside nvc's visible controller:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Result
[image: Blank Screen]

Any ideas why this could happen?

**UPDATE**:
I realized this only happens when before dismissing the view, I update a value in a shared singleton class, I use to keep track of events.

```
[[SAStatus current] setValue:@(ua_photoSubmitted) forKeyPath:@"actions.user"];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But it works fine if I do this:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
   [[SAStatus current] setValue:@(ua_photoSubmitted) forKeyPath:@"actions.user"];
}];
```

or I can do this and it also works fine:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

           [[SAStatus current] setValue:@(ua_photoSubmitted) forKeyPath:@"actions.user"];
 }];
```

At the time, no other classes observer that variable so I do not understand why it would affect the modal view.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter whether you call it on self or self.presentingViewController, they both should work. Whatever your problem was, it wasn't the code you said that you used.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that this is causing the black screen, but the presented view controller should call dismissViewController on itself, not on the presenting view controller.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Right, as the docs say "if you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that was not the issue. I updated about the issue above.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this issue with iOS 8 GM. Dismissing with animated set to NO did the trick.

Comment: How is this a solution?, *sigh*

Comment: It's a temporary solution until Apple fixes it! Maybe you can instead use the iOS 7 custom transition APIs.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.0.1 with the official iOS 8 Developer Kit and the problem seems not to have been fixed yet. Setting animated=NO still fixes the problem, however. Thanks a lot!